# FragmentLayout overlapping content

Tags: android

The `FraglemtLayout` bar is overlapping the content of the page.
i.e. My `TabLayout` is overlapping the main content of the page.

This is MainActivity layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.example.feelingoodlivinbeta.socialdreams_a1.MainMenuActivity"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context="com.example.feelingoodlivinbeta.socialdreams_a1.MainMenuActivity">


        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >

        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is model layout contains cardview; I don't know where the problem is located

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_below="@id/fragmantRecycler">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="56dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.06"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/socialdreamlogo" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nameTxt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="3.67"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="TextView" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/placeholder" />


    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

[image]

Comment: Where is it overlapping the content?

Comment: @Dennis The fragment tabs is over the picture, I cant c all the details

Comment: Sorry if I sound dumb, but it's so confusing. What's your fragment tab? Seems ok to me.

Comment: @Dennis lolz no its me im new to android, the tabs with the house, fire and heart picture is over the content of the page. the content should start under the tabs but the tab is going over it

Comment: This is how it is supposed to be done. You can think of it as Another `AppBar` with a swipe functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems to be related to this line:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.example.feelingoodlivinbeta.socialdreams_a1.MainMenuActivity"
```

replace it with:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Comment: thnx thnx thnx, I would have neva found that error, thnk u much:)